# C Newbie: Split a number into pairs and sum up

Tags: c

I'm teaching myself C (not C++, not yet). After searching the web in general and SO specifically for a couple of hours, I'm still stumped on how to do something fairly basic. Split a number into pairs, then sum those pairs. Something like:

1234567890 --> 
12 + 34 + 56 +78 + 90 = 270

I tried treating the number as a string, putting it into an array, splitting off each number and then concatenating those into pairs, and started getting lost around that point.

What's the best way to do this? Do I have to treat the number as a string to get the pairs, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

> What's the best way to do this? Do I have to treat the number as a
>   string to get the pairs, or is there a better way?

You could do

```
while (number) {
    x = number % 100; /* Get the last two digits. */
    number /= 100; /* Get rid of them. */
}
```

It also depends on what you plan to do if you have an odd number of digits.

Comment: cnicutar, that's genius. I knew I was heading down the wrong road with the whole "convert num to string" idea, but couldn't come up with anything better. Using the mod operator makes sense, thanks!